# how can i get the membership,roles and access rules in an web application after deployment

Tags: asp.net

I am using website administration tool for membership,role and access rules.It is working fine in development machine,but in server not woking.In server VS IDE is not installed.How can i get the membership,roles and access rules in server after deployment.Please help

Thanks&Regards
Lijo

Answer (score 0):

Use the ASP.NET SQL Server Registration Tool from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx

More info on that page too.

Update: You don't need VS IDE installed, just the .Net Framework

Answer (score 0):

You've probably just set up the ASPNETDB.mdb file that attaches to your SQL Server Express Instance. That normally won't work on the server, so you'll need to recreate the tables and procedures in your production database.

You can use the aspnet_regsql.exe tool to set up the correct tables etc. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx and as @amaters mentions, here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx