# Website authentication

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I just want to know if there is a method to add a username and password by editing the file ( machine.config ) or another one rather than using Asp.net configuration ?

Comment: Yes, its possible. No, its not recommended. (Really, no!)

Comment: thanks Arjan but if you know the way tell me just to try because I am unable to add them using asp.net configuration ..

Comment: You would probably be better of finding out why ASP.NET configuration won't work and fix it, than follow this solution. (Though, complete answer given below)

Comment: Now that I read your other question here on SO, about the problem with ASP.NET Configuration. There's an answer, and you could start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352117/how-can-i-get-the-membership-roles-and-access-rules-in-an-web-application-after/10352230#10352230

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

The password format should be either way:

```
<credentials 
   passwordFormat="[Clear|SHA1|MD5]">
  <user/>
</credentials>
```

And in web.config you can modify as below:

For example:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
         <forms name="your app name" loginUrl="/login.aspx">
            <credentials passwordFormat = "SHA1">
               <user 
                  name="UserName1" 
                  password="SHA1EncryptedPassword1"/>
               <user 
                  name="UserName2" 
                  password="SHA1EncryptedPassword2"/>
               <user 
                  name="UserName3" 
                  password="SHA1EncryptedPassword3"/>
            </credentials>
         </forms>
      </authentication>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And you can have a look from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e01fc50a.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This goes in the web.config file, inside the `system.web` element:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms>
    <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1">
      <user name="moses"
            password="02726D40F378E716981C4321D60BA3A325ED6A4C" /> <!-- Pa$$w0rd -->
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

The C# to authenticate the user:

```
if(FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password))  // You supply the username and password
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
}
```